# Loop inside the function that accepts the parameter

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

```
let printNumber = (num) => {
for (let i = 0; i <= num.length; i++){
  num += i;
}
return num
}
 console.log(printNumber(4));
```

the output should be from 0 to num like examples
output:
0
1
2
3
4

how should I fix my code?

Comment: Numbers don't have a `.length` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your code to

```js
let printNumber = (num) => {
for (let i = 0; i < num+1; i++){
  console.log(i)
}
}
printNumber(4);
```

This will give you your desired output..
1 You were returning numbers which was not required as you can console log from the function
2 The parameter was a number not a array that you need to use .length function